# Can we expect find constant $C>0$ so that $(x+y)^r\geq C( x^{r}+y^r)$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $x, y >0, r>0.$ Assume that $r\notin \mathbb N.$

> Can we say that  $(x+y)^r\geq x^{r}+y^r$?

Edit: In view  of the answer below: I'm modifying my question:

> Can we expect to find a constant $C>0$ so that
>   $(x+y)^r\geq C( x^{r}+y^r)$?

Comment: @PF: Thanks. How should I justify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Let $x=y=1$, then you are claiming $2^r\geq 2$ for all noninteger $r>0$, which fails to hold for all $r\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks: Ok, I got. Can we expect  $(x+y)^r\geq C (x^r+y^r)$ for some constant ?

Comment: Yes with $C=\frac12$.  Follows from trivial bound $(x+y)^r\geq x^r$ and $(x+y)^r\geq y^r$.

Answer (score 3):

To the modified question: yes, and $C=1/2$ will do. Since $y>0$, $(x+y)^r>x^r$, and similarly $(x+y)^r>y^r$. One of $x^r$ and $y^r$ must be at least $\frac{x^r+y^r}2$, so $(x+y)^r>\frac{x^r+y^r}2$.

user10354138's answer shows that you cannot do better than $1/2$ in general: for any $C>1/2$ there is an $r$ sufficiently small for which the inequality would fail.